# How to catagorize a list with same prefix/suffix?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of words as below:

```
Data = ['pre_bbc', 'pre_nbc', 'pre_fox', 'bread_post', 'pre_news', 'lucky_post',
'banana_post', 'mike', 'john', 'edward_lear', 'winelistpdf', 'cookbookspdf']
```

Assuming I have no idea of what the prefix or suffix is beforehand, and '_' is not always the case to split suffix/prefix, is there a way using Python to catagorize this list into  groups? Let's say the result I want is as below:

```
List0 = ['pre_bbc', 'pre_nbc', 'pre_fox', 'pre_news']
List1 = ['bread_post', 'lucky_post', 'banana_post']
List2 = ['winelistpdf', 'cookbookspdf']
Orphan_list =['mike', 'john', 'edward_lear']
```

There could be some tricky cases in which a word contains both suffix and prefix, like 'pre_voa_post', I think this can be put into both lists. Also, let's assume all the elements are unique in this list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a pretty challenging one! There are a few conditions to consider here if this needs to be fairly universal.

- Minimum length for an affix
- Delimiters that denote affixes
- Multiple affixes

```py
import json

def get_affix_groups(words, min=3, delimiter="_"):
    """Get groups from a word list that have matching affixes."""
    groups = {}
    for word in words:
        for item in [w for w in words if w != word]:
            for n in range(len(word) - min):
                try:
                    prefix, *_, suffix = word.split(delimiter)
                except ValueError:
                    prefix = word[:n + min]
                    suffix = word[-(n + min):]

                if item.startswith(prefix):
                    prefix_group = groups.setdefault(prefix, {word})
                    groups[prefix].add(item)

                if item.endswith(suffix):
                    suffix_group = groups.setdefault(suffix, {word})
                    groups[suffix].add(item)

    all_words = [i for w in groups.values() for i in w]
    groups["orphans"] = {word for word in words if word not in all_words}

    return groups

data = [
    "pre_bbc",
    "pre_nbc",
    "pre_fox",
    "bread_post",
    "pre_news",
    "lucky_post",
    "banana_post",
    "mike",
    "john",
    "edward_lear",
    "winelistpdf",
    "cookbookspdf",
    "pre_voa_post"
]

# Print the resulting dict in a human-readable format
print(json.dumps(get_affix_groups(data), default=list, indent=2))
```

### Output

```
{
  "pre": [
    "pre_fox",
    "pre_voa_post",
    "pre_bbc",
    "pre_news",
    "pre_nbc"
  ],
  "post": [
    "lucky_post",
    "pre_voa_post",
    "bread_post",
    "banana_post"
  ],
  "pdf": [
    "cookbookspdf",
    "winelistpdf"
  ],
  "orphans": [
    "john",
    "edward_lear",
    "mike"
  ]
}
```

If you *really* need these to be variables, you can use `exec()`, but [it's considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/4881095).

```py
for affix, group in get_affix_groups(data).items():
    exec(f"{affix} = {group}")
```

Comment: Sam, very nice job! I think you made it and also provided insights to more generic cases. I found another post (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145757/finding-a-common-prefix-suffix-in-a-list-tuple-of-strings) is also inspiring using iterator, though it's not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with :

```
    Data = ['pre_voa_post', 'argument', 'thermodynamic', 'winelistpdf', 
           'pre_bbc', 'anteroom', 'pre_nbc', 'thermostat', 'pre_fox', 
           'antedate', 'blabla', 'enchantment', 'pre_news', 'lucky_post', 
          'banana_post', 'mike', 'john', 'thermometer', 'toto', 'antenatal' ]
```

Function

```
def test(Data):
    suffixes = Data.copy()
    prefixes = Data.copy()
    my_suffixes = {}
    my_prefixes = {}
    Orphan_list = []
    Orphan_s = []
    Orphan_p = []
    while len(prefixes) > 1:
        first_p = prefixes.pop(0)
        prefix = ''
        for elt_pref in prefixes:
            i = min(len(first_p), len(elt_pref))
            while i > 1:
                if first_p[0:i] == elt_pref[0:i]:
                    prefix = first_p[0:i]
                    my_prefixes[prefix] = [first_p, elt_pref, ]
                    prefixes.remove(elt_pref)
                    var = 0
                    while var < len(prefixes):
                        sec_elt = prefixes[var]
                        if sec_elt.startswith(prefix):
                            my_prefixes[prefix].append(sec_elt)
                            prefixes.remove(sec_elt)
                        else:
                            var += 1
                    break
                else:
                    i -= 1
        if prefix == '':
            Orphan_p.append(first_p)
    if prefixes:
        Orphan_p.append(prefixes[0])

    while len(suffixes) > 1:
        first_s = suffixes.pop(0)
        suffix = ''
        for elt_suf in suffixes:
            j = min(len(first_s), len(elt_suf))
            while j > 2:
                if first_s[-j:] == elt_suf[-j:]:
                    suffix = first_s[-j:]
                    my_suffixes[suffix] = [first_s, elt_suf, ]
                    suffixes.remove(elt_suf)
                    var = 0
                    while var < len(suffixes):
                        elt_suf3 = suffixes[var]
                        if elt_suf3.endswith(suffix):
                            my_suffixes[suffix].append(elt_suf3)
                            suffixes.remove(elt_suf3)
                        else:
                            var += 1
                    break
                else:
                    j -= 1
        if suffix == '':
            Orphan_s.append(first_s)
    if suffixes:
        Orphan_s.append(suffixes[0])
    Orphan_list = list(set(Orphan_p) & set(Orphan_s))
    print("my_suffixes", my_suffixes)
    print("my_prefixes", my_prefixes)
    print("Orphan_list", Orphan_list)
```

Result:

```
my_suffixes {'_post': ['pre_voa_post', 'bread_post', 'lucky_post', 'banana_post'], 
              'ment': ['argument', 'enchantment'], 
               'pdf': ['winelistpdf', 'cookbookspdf']}

my_prefixes {'pre_': ['pre_voa_post', 'pre_bbc', 'pre_nbc', 'pre_fox', 'pre_news'],
           'thermo': ['thermodynamic', 'thermostat', 'thermometer'], 
           'ante': ['anteroom', 'antedate', 'antenatal']}


Orphan_list ['toto', 'mike', 'john', 'blabla', 'edward_lear']
```

Comment: And as you see, there is no conditions

Comment: Done, with tree results: dist of suffixes, dict of prefixes, and the Orphan list,                              You can find the same word in suffixes and prefixes like  "pre_voa_post"

Answer (score 0):

this should not be a valid question, but:

```
def partition(list_of_pref, list_of_words):
    ret_list = []
    for l in list_of_pref:
        this_list = []
        ret_list.append(this_list)
        for word in list_of_words:
            if word.startswith(l):
                this_list.append(word)


partition(['pre', 'banana'],['pre_bbc', 'pre_nbc', 'pre_fox', 'bread_post', 'pre_news', 'lucky_post', 'banana_post', 'mike', 'john', 'edward_lear', 'winelistpdf', 'cookbookspdf'])                                                               
Out[4]: [['pre_bbc', 'pre_nbc', 'pre_fox', 'pre_news'], ['banana_post']]
    return ret_list
```

do the same with list of pref, or generate them by iterating on split('_') inside your function and you are done

Comment: if you read ```do the same with list of pref, or generate them by iterating on split('_') inside your function and you are done```

Comment: Prefix and suffix are not always seperated by _

Comment: I don't know, would it? What have you exactly tried, what are you stuck on, etc